# AlertDialog reappears on rotation

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I know that this has already been asked a lot of times but no answer could help me.

I have a dialog which will pop up at a certain moment (when I call method "showServerDialog").
The dialog is shown and everything is fine until I dismiss the dialog using a "negativeButton" and then rotate the screen. Then the dialog reappears although I dismissed it.

I read a lot of times that android handles everything automatically if I show the dialog using the showDialog(int id) method and override the onCreateDialog(int id) method. And that's exactly what I'm doing:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void showServerDialog(int position){
    showDialog(REMOVE_SERVER_DIALOG_ID);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch (id) {
    case REMOVE_SERVER_DIALOG_ID:

        System.out.println("---------------------------------DIALOG");

        // Create AlterDialog
        Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("This will end the activity");
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton("I agree", new OkOnClickListener());
        builder.setNegativeButton("No, no", new CancelOnClickListener());

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        return dialog;
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}

private final class CancelOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Do nothing and just close dialog
    }
}
```

But then, when I close the dialog normally using a button in the dialog and rotate the screen then it just reappears.

I'm totally stuck with it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, finally I found an answer:

Instead of doing nothing in the OnClickListeners I have to call:
MyActivity.this.removeDialog(REMOVE_SERVER_DIALOG_ID);

not dismiss! This works!

Answer (score -2):

Had the same problem ,fixed this with following line in my `manifest.xml`

```
        <activity 
        ...
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        />
```

You could try this :)

Comment: I really don't want to add this because I still want my app to create itself again when rotating.